# How can I sort an array of arrays (by variable name) using Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

(I'm not using Swift 2.0 at the time.)

I have multiple arrays inside a master array. I need them in alphabetical order by variable name, and I can't figure out how to sort anything other than Strings inside an array. These are my arrays:

```
var onDeck1 = [String]()
var onDeck2 = [String]()
var onDeck3 = [String]()
var onDeck4 = [String]()
```

My problem is that I keep running into something like this:

```
var masterArray = [onDeck1, onDeck4, onDeck3, onDeck2]
```

When I need this:

```
var masterArray = [onDeck1, onDeck2, onDeck3, onDeck4]
```

Anybody know what I need to do?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you want. Do you want the arrays inside the masterArray to be sorted alphabetically based on the _variable_ name?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I am sorry if it was unclear, but I did give an example of what I have vs what I need.

Comment: So how do you go about constructing the masterArray in the first place?

Comment: It's actually a bit complicated. I'm chaining Parse.com queries. When I retrieve query results up to the query limit, I sort them into the onDeck arrays. After that, I append the onDeck arrays to masterArray. The problem arises when one of my queries is cut off by the query limit (for example, during results that belong in onDeck3). My code then appends the remaining results in the next query, but not necessarily in the correct order.

Comment: That doesn't sound like your original question at all.

Comment: That's because it's not... I was asked how my array was constructed, and I answered. My original question remains the same. I need to know how to sort an array of arrays by the names of the contained arrays.

Comment: Swift-reflection is still fairly rudimentary so I think the simple answer is that this can't be done in Swift. So, you need to find a more pragmatic approach, either changing what you actually do when you parse from Parse or you could make a struct containing your deck-array and a string-identifier...

Answer (score 0):

Try the following approach:

```
// var masterArray = [ onDeck1, onDeck4, onDeck3,onDeck2]

var masterArray = [ "Babisko", "Kapisko", "Hapisko"];
var sortedArray = masterArray.sorted { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare($1) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
```

Comment: No luck. Error message: 

    Cannot invoke 'sorted' with an argument list of type '((_,_) -> _)'

Comment: Please retry again because I have just changed a small thing in the answer.

Comment: Oh, wait. The string are sorted just fine. It's just that I can't sort the arrays.

Comment: This doesn't order by _variable_ name. This just order strings by insensitive compare order.